# Is it necessary that the chromatic polynomial must be a function of K and N?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is it a necessary condition that we must use the `K (number of colors)` and `N (number of vertices)` to make the chromatic polynomial of a graph? Can we use other parameters such as **the number of edges** in a chromatic polynomial?

If it's not a necessary condition, is there any example that uses of other parameters in the chromatic polynomial?

Comment: You certainly need $k$. You don't need any other parameters, though, for a fixed graph $G$. The value of $n$ only shows up if you have a family of graphs parameterized by the size of their vertex-sets (such as the complete graphs). So, in some cases, you might be able to use the number of edges in a formula for the chromatic polynomial of a family of graphs. No examples come to mind, though.